# how to use <div id="SomeId"></div> for navigation purpose

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all as per the requirement to create a slider I found following link [Reference 1](http://nimbupani.com/making-pure-css3-demos-better.html)

That I have implemented successfully, but when we started to put asp.net code it started to create problem(s). However I am able to solve many of them but the one where I have trapped up. I want your guidance in this.

**Problem:** I want to move "Sub Page Content 2" once the user has submitted form1 of  Sub page Content 1 automatically. 
I am able to jump to tab Page2 but not able to move the contents of Sub page Content 1 to the left automatically using `jquery`.

In order to **solve** this I have found many threads here, giving solution to move `jquery ui tab` widget. However I want to understand the code structure written below too.

```
<div class="main_main_container">
  <div id="linktoPage1">
    <div id="linktoPage2">
        <div id="linktoPage3">
            <div id="linktoPage4">
                <nav> <a href="#linktoPage1">Page1</a><a href="#linktoPage2">Page2</a><a href="#linktoPage3">Page3</a><a 

href="#linktoPage4"></nav>
                <div class="Pages">
                        <div class="page" id="subPage1"> Sub Page Content 1 
            full flag asp.net form1
        </div>  
                        <div class="page" id="subPage2"> Sub Page Content 2
            full flag asp.net form2
         </div>
                        <div class="page" id="subPage3"> Sub Page Content 3 
            full flag asp.net form3
        </div>
                        <div class="page" id="subPage4"> Sub Page Content 4 
            full flag asp.net form4
        </div> 
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is identical to the code defined at [Reference 1](http://nimbupani.com/making-pure-css3-demos-better.html)

In order to understand this code structure I have taken help of following page 
 [w3org_site,](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1) [vanseocom](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/click-events/), [tympanus_web](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/)

At `w3org` site I have found the following that gave me little help to understand the above html code.

> (as described on the w3org)

---

### Destination anchors

```
 <p> <a href="#section1"> History Notes </a>     
    <a href="#section2"> Maths Notes </a>     
    <a href="#section3"> Social Science Notes </a>
         </p>
```

> Method 1:

```
<H2><A name="section1">History Notes </A></H2>
    ...section 1...
    <H2><A name="section2">Maths Notes </A></H2>
    ...section 2...
```

or

> Method 2:

We may achieve the same effect by making the header elements themselves the anchors:

```
<H2 id="section1">History Notes </A></H2>
    ...section 1...
    <H2 id="section2">Maths Notes </A></H2>
    ...section 2...
```

Now this description made me confuse regarding the code described on `w3org` because it is totally different code than the described at `Reference 1` site.

why they are not using `#`character to direct(send) the user to the description of link History Notes.
And why in the code on the `Reference 1` author have written like `<div id="linktoPage1">` and writing `<a href="#linktoPage1">` inside/nesting within `<div id="linktoPage4">`

This is a special type of *cssistry* (chemistry) here that I am not able to grasp.

I am hoping once i would be able to understand the above *cssistry* I am going to find answer of following question. It has described above also.

author is using css way to direct the user to specified location. then how we can perform the same using jquery. I meant how we ll able to write equivalent code of `#linktoPage1:target .page(left:-100%);` using `jquery`.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note to Method 1: Since html5 the `name` attribte for `a` elements is obsolete ([11.1 Obsolete but conforming features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features)`[...]Authors should not specify the name attribute on a elements.[...]The id attribute should be used instead.`)

Comment: The text on the W3C page was written many years ago, and Method 1 was used for compatibility with older browsers. That is to say, 20th century browsers, which totally don't exist any more. You can always use the ID method, even in browsers as old as IE6. (I just tested).

Comment: By the way, clicking does not have anything to do with CSS.

Comment: @MrLister thank you for your response. However, sir, you may find that (on the page  'Reference 1`) is making use of css to support click. and also it is visible on 'vanseo' blog too.. please take them in consideration too. Thank you!

Comment: @MrLister could you please give me a clue 
    `<div class="main">
  <div id="link1">
    <div id="link2">
                     <nav> <a href="#link1">Page1</a><a href="#link2">Page2</a></nav>
                <div class="Pages">
                        <div class="page" id="sub1"> pg1
        </div>  
                        ...many other link...
                        
                        </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>`
that how this code work

Comment: I'm not sure what the real question is now. You want to understand how the CSS pseudo-class `:target` works? Or do you want to know how to translate this to jQuery, and if so, what is your goal? To avoid `:target`?

Comment: actually, earlier order was to create a slider and in that `asp.net forms` will be put. That I have achieved. But lack of experience I was not sure whether this will be easy to manage using `java script` or not. after a few searches I reached to the point first of all I should understand how this code is working then I should work upon how this could be convert into `jquery code` .. This is my two step goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tabbed menu you're using is designed so that it's not possible to select a tab with JS.

The menu works so, that all the elements are wrapped inside three wrappers, one of which is targeted by clicking on a link. The pages are given styling based on which wrapper element was targeted. The problem is that you can't `target` an element using JS, which is why you can't select a tab using JS with your current code.

But don't worry, that's a bad way to do CSS-only tabs anyway. If you do it the way shown in the tutorial you referred to, none of the tabs appear to be selected initially before the user clicks on one of the tabs. Also, it requires a lot of excess markup.

I suggest you use `radio buttons` instead (if you want the tab menu navigation to work purely with CSS despite using JS for some other things anyway). The advantages of using `radio buttons`:

- you can use JS to select a tab with `element.checked=true;`
- you can have one of the tabs pre-selected with the `checked` attribute
- there's much less markup cluttering your HTML
- still pure CSS solution

I already created a function `tab()` which you can use to select one of the tabs. For instance, `tab(3)` would select the third tab.

I tried to go into as much detail as I could in the comments of the code below. But I understand that it requires quite a good knowledge of CSS selectors to fully comprehend, so ask if something's unclear.

```js
/*
With the following function you can select a tab to be displayed:
tab(1) selects the first tab for instance.
*/
function tab(number){
    var elems=document.getElementsByTagName("input"), navs=[];
    for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) if(elems[i].getAttribute("name")=="nav") navs.push(elems[i]);
    navs[number-1].checked=true;
}
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
/* 
You can select input elements whose name attribute is "nav" using 
the [attribute=value] selector to select all our radio buttons
that'll become the tabs:
*/
input[name=nav]{ 
    width: calc(100% / 3); /* third of the screen width */
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2; /* this is so the ::before pseudo elements would be on top of the pages */
}
/*
To give separate styling for the second and the third tabs, you can use
the same selector again to target them specifically:
*/
input[value=i2]{
    left:calc(100% / 3);
}
input[value=i3]{
    left:calc(200% / 3);
}
/* 
Radio buttons can't be styled, but the trick is to create an ::after
pseudo element and place it on top of the radio button. When the user
clicks on a pseudo element, it activates its parent selecting it. So,
in a nutshell, give the ::after pseudo element the styles you would for
the radio button. 
*/
input[name=nav]::after{
    content: attr(data-title); /* Display the value of the data-title attribute inside the element. */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; /* Position it on top of its parent */
    width: 100%; height: 100%; /* Make it the size as its parent */
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 2em/1 helvetica, arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
    transition: background 1s;
}
input[name=nav]:hover::after{ /* styling when hovering */
    background-color: #444;
}
input[name=nav]:checked::after{ /* styling when the tab is selected */
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}
/*
Now the ::after pseudo elements are enough for the tabs to work, but if
you want to have the back and forward buttons, you should create these
::before pseudo elements also. They work with the same idea. This time however,
their position is fixed so they can be placed on top of the pages.

Of course the back and forward buttons should only appear for tabs that 
aren't currently selected, for which you can use  the :not(:checked) selector:
*/
input[name=nav]:not(:checked)::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    width: 50vw;
}
input[value=i1]:not(:checked)::before{
    width:100vw;
}
input[value=i1]:checked ~ input[value=i3]::before{
    left:0;
}
input[value=i1]:checked ~ input[value=i2]::before{
    left:50vw;
}
input[value=i2]:checked ~ input[value=i3]::before{
    left:50vw;
}
.pages{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: left 0.8s;
    transition: left 0.8s;
}
.page{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.page#1 {
    background-color: #bbb;
    left: 0;
}
.page#i2 {
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: 100%;
}
.page#i3 {
    background-color: #ddd;
    left: 200%;
}
/*
Finally, use the "after" ~ selector to determine which page to show. The idea here is 
that we first match which of the radio buttons are selected and then look for a .pages
element that follows it. This is the reason you shouldn't wrap the navigation elements
 - they need to be on the same level in the DOM tree.

So, for instance if the first tab is selected, then input[value=i1]:checked is matched
and we can style the .pages element with the ~ selector because it comes after the 
matched radio button in the DOM tree.
*/
input[value=i1]:checked ~ .pages {
    left: 0%;
}
input[value=i2]:checked ~ .pages {
    left: -100%;
}
input[value=i3]:checked ~ .pages {
    left: -200%;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is the navigation. It needs to be on the same level as 
the pages in the DOM tree for the ~ selector to work, so don't 
wrap it. Put the title you want displayed in the data-title
attribute. -->
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="i1" data-title="Tab 1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="i2" data-title="Tab 2">
<input type="radio" name="nav" value="i3" data-title="Tab 3">
<!-- And here are your pages: -->
<div class="pages">
    <div id="i1" class="page">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="i2" class="page">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="i3" class="page">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Oksanen: Thank you so much for such detailed answer. I really need of such insightful answer. You are absolutely correct as I am really writing excessive HTML and CSS for this. and even JavaScript also has crossed over 100 lines in order to display the right selected tab.(as you already know there are `asp.net` forms) Page has became very heavy in itself. I have started to apply your solution; and I have got many questions too. But I would ask rather important question. thanks again!